# In my code i am trying to create rooms but i don't know why every time it create old rooms with new one

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This my server.js file. In this i am creating a new room on every create 
room request and then push that created room into the rooms array. 
Username and roomname is taken form the form by post request.But i don't know why it is creating all the previous rooms every time with new socket id
like. If i give it a username:abc and roomname:room1 first time it will create a room then next time if i would create a room username:abc2 and  roomname:room2 with new socket connection at that time it would again create the old room(username:abc,roomname:room1) first and increase the rooms array length and then create the new room(username:abc2,roomname:room2) and increase the length of rooms array.

```
//server.js


const express = require('express');
const app = new express();
const socket = require('socket.io');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = app.listen(port,() =>{
    console.log(`server is running on the port number ${port}`);
})


const io = socket(server);


app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',`${__dirname}/views`);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
let rooms = [];

function pushRoom(rooms,usernme,roomname){
let room = {
    name:roomname,
    users:[]
}
 room.users.push(usernme);
 rooms.push(room);
} 

function joinRoom(rooms,roomjoinname,username){
for(let i=0 ; i<rooms.length ; i++){
    if(rooms[i].name == roomjoinname){
        rooms[i].users.push(username);
    }
}
}

app.get('/',(req,res,next) =>{
 res.render('index');
})

//taking values from user by post request

    app.post('/chat',(req,res,next) =>{
        io.on('connection',socket =>{
        console.log('made a socket connection'+socket.id);
        let roomName = req.body.roomName;
        let userName = req.body.username;
        let roomNameJoin = req.body.roomNameJoin;
            pushRoom(rooms,userName,roomName);
            socket.join('roomName');
});
res.render('chat');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reason for repeated additions

This is because every time a user visits the `/chat` page you add a new listener to your socket.io server. So if 3 users have visited the `/chat` page, 3 event listeners will have been registered for the `connection` event. This means that when a new `connection` will be made at that point, the 3 registered listeners will be executed and three new rooms will be pushed to your array.

## Suggestion that removes unwanted behaviour

Put your room creation outside the socket.io `connection` event handler and put your `connection` handler registration outside of your HTTP `post` handler.

```
app.post('/chat', (req,res,next) => {
  let roomName = req.body.roomName;
  let userName = req.body.username;
  pushRoom(rooms,userName,roomName);
  res.render('chat');
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('made a socket connection'+socket.id);
  socket.join('roomName');
});
```